# 20.04 and BenQ Monitor Connectivity Problem

Tags: 20.04, amd-graphics, 4k-monitor

I am baffled by the Ubuntu connectivity problem between my Lenovo M83 desktop and a new BenQ 4K display.  I can connect to the monitor using the Ubuntu Live USB images, and from Win 7 Pro on my dual-boot system.  But, I am unable to connect from the hard file install of Ubuntu 18.04 or the 20.04.

**Background**

I have a dual boot Lenovo M83 desktops system with a Radeon HD 8570 video card that has a HDMI and a VGA output connector.  The M83 was initially a dual boot Win 7 Pro and Linux Mint 17 system, then in early 2020 I did a clean install of Ubuntu 18.04.

The video problems started when my old 24” monitor died in Nov 2020, and I purchased a BenQ PD3200U 4K monitor.  I had difficulty getting the new monitor to work with 18.04, but it was finally stable for several months.  Then. in March, the Ubuntu 18.04 video failed to connect to the BenQ monitor.  I tried the Live Ubuntu 20.04 USB, and it detected and synced to the monitor.  So, I did an in-place upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04.  But, the in-place upgrade to 20.04 also failed to connect to the monitor.  Next. I did a clean install of 20.04 which also fails to connect to the monitor.

**Hardware**

Lenovo M83 ThinkCenter

Settings > About

Intel® Core™ i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz × 8
Memory: 15.6 GiB
Disk: 6.0 TB
Graphics: AMD® Oland
Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, 64-bit,
GNOME: 3.36.8
Window System: X11

**Radeon Video Card**

sudo lshw -c video

*-display
description: VGA compatible controller
product: Oland [Radeon HD 8570 / R7 240/340 / Radeon 520 OEM]
vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
version: 00
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
resources: irq:29 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f7e00000-f7e3ffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:c0000-dffff

The Ubuntu video driver is identified as “radeon”.

**HDMI Cables**

I  used 3 different HDMI cables to connect from the video card to the monitor.  All 3 cables are 4K rated.

```
• HDMI-01 is a direct wire connection between the HDMI cable connectors
• HDMI-02, is a Smart cable from vendor one.  The connectors have a built-in transmitter and receiver which reduces the cable diameter.
• HDMI-03, another Smart cable from a different vendor.
```

**BenQ Monitor**

Model PD3200U
• 2 HDMI connectors
• 1 Display Port connectors
• 1 Mini Display Port connector
• (no VGA connector)

**OS Software**

```
• Ubuntu 18.04 Live USB Flash Drive, Apr 2018 download
• Ubuntu 18.04 installed on the desktop as a dual boot with Windows 7 Pro
• Ubuntu 20.04 Live USB Flash Drive, downloaded 13 Oct 2020
• Ubuntu 20.04 installed as an in-place upgrade using Software Updater (dual boot)
• Ubuntu 20.04 clean install from the USB flash drive (dual boot)
• Ubuntu 21.04 Live USB Flash Drive, downloaded 27 Apr 2021
• Windows 7 Pro (dual boot)
```

**Video Drivers**

```
• Ubuntu – “radeon” on all 3 Live USB images, and the 18.04 and 20.04 hard file installs.
• Windows – AMD, 11-20-2014, 14.501.1003.0
```

I am currently connected to the video card VGA port using a lower resolution monitor (1280 x 1024 max @ 60 Hz) with a 4:3 aspect ratio with the HDMI port disconnected.  Plugging the HDMI cable to the video card results in the loss of the VGA screen, only a mouse cursor on the VGA screen and nothing on the BenQ monitor.

**Discovery & Testing**

***Ubuntu Live USB (18.04, 20.04 and 21.04)***

I booted the “Live” desktop using 3 different versions of the Ubuntu Live USB Flash Drive: 18.04, 20.04 and 21.04.  I connected to the monitor using the 3 different HDMI cables.  The VGA monitor was disconnected.  The same boot sequence occurred with the 3 Ubuntu USB versions using the 3 cables.

```
• Lenovo splash screen
• Ubuntu Live boot splash screen
• Ubuntu Live desktops (18.04, 20.04, and 21.04)
• Monitor resolution was 4 k, 3860 x 2160 @ 30 Hz
• No problems booting the system or using the “Try Linux” desktop
• Other resolutions and display options available from Settings > Display
```

***Windows 7 Pro***

Tested the Windows 7 Pro connectivity with the monitor and the 3 different HDMI cables.

```
• Lenovo splash screen
• Grub menu, Boot Windows
• Windows splash screen, Windows login menu screen
• No login problems using a user or admin account
• Connects using all 3 HDMI cables
• Desktop resolution: 1920x1080.  This was the previous display setting that I was using.  Other resolutions are available on the Display Setup drop-down menu.
```

***Ubuntu 18.04 Dual-Boot Image***

Ubuntu 18.04 worked with my old 24” monitor for over a year at a lower resolution (I did not record the resolution, but I think it was 1920x1080).  When that monitor died, I purchased the BenQ monitor thinking it was time to upgrade to a 4K monitor.  I had some initial setup problems, but I finally had the system connecting to the monitor at the 1920x1080 resolution due to the limitations of my KVM hardware.  The 18.04 boot stopped connecting in March 2021.  As I sorted through the various failure possibilities, I bypassed the KVM and connected the monitor directly to the system.  I had used the video card to BenQ HDMI direct cabling when I first setup the BenQ monitor in Dec, and it worked at 4K at that time.

But, in March, the 18.04 stopped connecting.  Did one of the Ubuntu updates break the handshaking setup between the monitor and the video card?  I tried the 3 different HDMI cables, so I do not think this is a HDMI cable problem since the same cables connect with the Ubuntu Live USB images and with the Win 7 Pro dual boot.

***Ubuntu 20.04 (in-place upgrade and clean install)***

Since the 20.04 Live USB image was able to connect to the monitor, I thought it prudent to upgrade to 20.04 since I was planning to upgrade to 20.04 in the near future.  I used the Ubuntu in-place upgrade, which was successful with no error messages.  Yet the in-place upgrade failed to connect to the monitor.  So, I did a clean install of 20.04.  There were no error messages on the clean install.  The test data from boot sequence and the failures using the 3 different HDMI cables.

```
• Lenovo splash screen
• Grub, Ubuntu, default
• Ubuntu splash screen
• Then one of the following messages on the BenQ monitor
        1. No Signal – HDMI-01 and HDMI-02 cables
        2. No Cable – HDMI-03 cable
•   Blank BenQ screen, no login menu screen
```

Yet the same HDMI cables worked with the Live USB images and with Win 7 Pro.

I had to revert to using the VGA output connected to a different lower resolution monitor (1280x1020 max) in order to use Ubuntu.

**Possible Failure Mechanism**

BenQ PD3200 Monitor, maybe, this is the new piece of hardware in my setup.  Yet it works with the 3 Ubuntu Live USB images (18.04, 20.04 and 21.04), and with Win 7 Pro.  So what type of problem could cause a connectivity failure from the dual-boot hard file Ubuntu image (18.04 or 20.04)?  I suspect a handshake and sync problem.

HDMI Cables, unlikely, all 3 cables connect with the Ubuntu Live USB images and with Win 7 Pro.

Radeon Video Card hardware, unlikely, the hardware works with the USB images and with Win 7.  What could cause a problem with only the hard file Ubuntu images?

Ubuntu 18.04 on the hard file, maybe.  Ubuntu 18.04 worked with the old 24” monitor for about 1 year before the monitor died.  It also worked with the new BenQ monitor for several months.  But, in March it suddenly stopped connecting via the KVM or with direct HDMI cables.

Ubuntu 20.04 installed on the hard file, maybe, the Live USB images is updated by Ubuntu during the install process.  Did some update break the video setup handshake between Ubuntu and the monitor?  This might explain why the connectivity failed suddenly in March when I installed some of the periodic Ubuntu 18.04 updates.  But, I also tried the 21.04 Live USB image, which I think would include many of the 18.04 and 20.04 updates, and this image does connect properly.

Ubuntu, Radeon Video Driver, maybe, the same “radeon” driver was identified on the 3 Live USB images, the 18.04 hard file dual boot image, and both the in-place and clean install 20.04 images.  But, why would the “radeon” driver work with the Live USB images, and not the hard file images (18.04 or 20.04)?  Is something corrupting the driver on the hard file during the install and update process?

Lenovo Motherboard, unlikely, what would have changed suddenly in March, and why does the Live USB images and Win 7 Pro connect properly?

Win 7 Operating System & Video Driver, unlikely, different OS and video driver, but using the same motherboard and video card hardware.  The fact that this functions seems to eliminate motherboard and video card hardware issues.

**Some Question for the Forum:**

```
1. Why do the Ubuntu Live USB images display properly on the BenQ monitor, but not the images on the hard file?
2. Do I have a corrupt video driver on the system?
3. What driver or drivers are supported on this video card?
4. How do I uninstall the existing “radeon” driver without loosing monitor access using the VGA connection to the lower resolution monitor. 
5. What have I overlooked?
6. What next steps should I consider?
7. Your suggestions are welcome
```

Sorry for the long posting.
Thank you in advance for your assistance